# How to block write access to the array from Thread while reading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have two threads running parallel, and to get information about their internal results, I have created int array of length 8. With respect to their id, they can update relative area on the statu array. They are not let to write others area. Moreover, to correctly get and display statu array, I try to write getStatu method. While getting the result, I want to block others to write to the statu array; unfortunately, I donot get how to block other to write the statu array while I am getting and displaying result in getStatu method. How?

Note: If there is a part to cause misunderstood, tell me my friend, I will fix

```
class A{
    Semaphore semaphore;
    int [] statu;  // statu is of length 8

    void update(int idOfThread, int []statu_){
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            int idx = idOfThread * 4;

            statu[idx] = statu_[0];
            statu[idx+1] = statu_[1];
            statu[idx+2] = statu_[2];
            statu[idx+3] = statu_[3];
        } catch (...) {

        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    int[] getStatu(){
        // Block write access of threads
        //    display statu array
        //    return statu array as return value
        // release block, so threads can write to the array

    }
}
```

Comment: You might get this job done by `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`. But maybe you shouldn't. By this you would introduce a lot of contention and reduce concurrency of your threads... and yes. Either A is a `singleton` or `statu` and `semaphore` are static. Otherwise your threads would not synchronize as they would not share the common infrastructure.

Comment: Why dont you use `ReentrantLock` ?

Comment: @blafasel may you write demonstrative code segment and I want to reduce concurrency of two threads. Actually, why I should? They are updating two different places.

Comment: @prajeeshkumar I don't understand how `ReentrantLock` will help.

Comment: Use `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  
`update` method will do its job under `rwLock.writeLock().lock()` while `getStatu` will acess the array under `rwLock.readLock().lock()`.

Comment: @apangin may you share your comment as an answer with more clear way, then I will test it. If it is ok, I will mark as an validated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using another lock/snc mechanism than Semaphore, just a proposal to improve this a little.

Putting both status[4] arrays into a single array[8] is not hte best solution. Consider task A writing its quadruplet: it must lock out task B reading the same, but there's no point in locking out task B writing B's quadruplet, and vice versa.

Generally speaking, the granularity of what is being locked is one important factor: locking the entire database is nonsense (except for overall processing like backup), however locking individual fields of a record would produce excessive overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly better ways to get to where you want to, but only you know what you are trying to do. Going with your own scheme, there are things you are doing wrong. First thing, currently you are not achieving the granular locking you are planning to. For that you must have an array of semaphores. So the acquisition will look something like

```
semaphore[idOfThread].acquire();
```

Secondly, one thing you've not realised is that controlled access to data among threads is a co-operative activity. You cannot lock on one thread and not care to deal with locking on another and somehow impose the access control.

So unless the caller of your getStatu() will use the same set of semaphores when inspecting the array, your best bet is for getStatu() to make a new int[] array, copying segments of each thread after locking with the respective semaphore. So the array returned by getStatu() will be a snapshot at the point of call.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code it will work for you. call `afterStatu()` in it.

```
class A {

    Semaphore semaphore;
    int[] statu; // statu is of length 8

    private boolean stuck;

    public A() {
    }

    void update(int idOfThread, int[] statu_) {

        // if true, control will not go further
        while (stuck);

        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            int idx = idOfThread * 4;

            statu[idx] = statu_[0];
            statu[idx + 1] = statu_[1];
            statu[idx + 2] = statu_[2];
            statu[idx + 3] = statu_[3];
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    int[] getStatu() {
        // Block write access of threads
        stuck = true;
        // display statu array
        for (int eachStatu : statu) {
            System.out.println(eachStatu);
        }

        // return statu array as return value
        return statu;
    }

    public void afterStatu() {
        getStatu();
         // release block, so threads can write to the array
        stuck = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
int[] statu;

void update() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        // update statu
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

int[] getStatu() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        // return statu
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like ac3 said, only you know what you are trying to do.

Here's a solution that might be useful in the case where *every* thread that calls update() does so *frequently*, and calls to getStatu() are *infrequent.*  It's complex, but it allows most of the update() calls to happen without any locking at all.

```
static final int NUMBER_OF_WORKER_THREADS = ...;
final AtomicReference<CountDownLatch> pauseRequested = new AtomicReference<CountDownLatch>(null);
final Object lock = new Object();

int[] statu = ...

//called in "worker" thread.
void update() {
    if (pauseRequested.get() != null) {
        pause();
    }
    ... update my slots in statu[] array ...
}

private void pause() {
    notifyMasterThatIAmPaused();
    waitForMasterToLiftPauseRequest();
}

private void notifyMasterThatIAmPaused() {
    pauseRequested.get().countDown();
}

private void waitForMasterToLiftPauseRequest() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        while (pauseRequested.get() != null) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}

//called in "master" thread

int[] getStatu( ) {
    int[] result;
    CountDownLatch cdl = requestWorkersToPause();
    waitForWorkersToPause(cdl);
    result = Arrays.copyOf(statu, statu.length);
    liftPauseRequest();
    return result;
}

private CountDownLatch requestWorkersToPause() {
    cdl = new CountDownLatch(NUMBER_OF_WORKER_THREADS);
    pauseRequested.set(cdl);
    return cdl;
}

private void waitForWorkersToPause(CountDownLatch cdl) {
    cdl.await();
}

private void liftPauseRequest() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        pauseRequested.set(null);
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```